# Import a symbol from the Fourier font family

Tags: fonts, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font)

I would like to use a single symbol from the fourier family in mathmode in one of my formulae in my document. In the comprehensive symbol archive,

ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

on page 53, the \partial symbol in table 147 is what I am after. How can I manage this?

Comment: Does [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't remember where I got this from, but here's what I have in my custom .sty file:

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}%
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{futm}{m}{it}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{fourier}{FML}{futm}{m}{it}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\partialup}{\mathord}{fourier}{130} % Upright partial derivative symbol
```

I *think* that's the one you're looking for.

Comment: Works like a charm - now I just have to parse it. :-) Thanks for your help.

Comment: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape OML/jkp/m/n undefined, using OML/jkp/m/it instead ?

Answer (score 2):

Minute differences, but the symbol `\partial` in table 147 is actually the italic non-variant version (kahen's solution is the roman `\varpartial` symbol):

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{futm}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{fourieritalic}{FML}{futmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\fpartial}{\mathord}{fourieritalic}{64}
```

Comment: so to take a symbol from palatino, what code can we write?

Comment: @mert ``\usepackage{mathpazo}``?  Perhaps this question might help you [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386).