# Import \vec from fouriernc?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, vector

I am wondering how to import the `\vec` font from `fouriernc` (which is much better designed than that in other fonts families, but I don't like other designs in `fouriernc`) without affecting the font family (I am using `mathpple`).

I guess something like [Import a symbol from the Fourier font family](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27527/import-a-symbol-from-the-fourier-font-family) might work, but I have not idea how to find the index of the symbol (130 in that case of `\partialup`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}%
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{fouriernc}{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}%
\DeclareMathAccent{\fvec}{0}{fouriernc}{"7E}
```

**Test:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathpple}
\DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}%
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{fouriernc}{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}%
\DeclareMathAccent{\fvec}{0}{fouriernc}{"7E}

\begin{document}
$\fvec{\alpha}\vec{\alpha}$
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

> [image]

**A brief explanation:**

Type `\meaning\vec`, one will get `macro:−>\mathaccent"017E\relax`. This means the arrow of `\vec` is defined by symbol of class 0 (Ordinary), family 1, and position 7E (126 in Base 10). Alternatively, one can look up `vector` in `fourier-ml.afm`.