# Sans-serif partial derivative symbol?

Tags: fonts, symbols, pdftex, sans-serif, roman

How can I typeset a partial derivative symbol (∂) in an upright, sans-serif font?

I am using pdfLaTeX. I know this problem could be solved easily by switching to another engine — and feel free to post XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX solutions for the benefit of posterity if you wish — but I am specifically looking for a solution within pdfLaTeX.

---

Edited to add an image to contrast what LaTeX generates with what I want:

[image: partial derivative symbol in LaTeX and in Helvetica Neue]

Comment: If it's sans-serif and upright, is it still the partial symbol?

Comment: @Sverre: French traditional typography typesets partial symbol in upright shape. So I would say the answer is ‘yes’.

Comment: One could use the schwa symbol with ``tipa``, but it wouldn't be sans-serif.

Comment: If the answer turns out to be that I can have only one wish at a time, sans-serif is more important than upright.

Comment: Check the answers here.
http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27527/24974

Comment: @Sverre -- schwa isn't a partial symbol; it's a rotated lowercase "e".  for anyone who has had any exposure to phonetics it definitely wouldn't be recognized as a partial symbol.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, of course. I just thought of the schwa symbol from ``tipa`` as something approximating what the OP is after. And you'd be surprised, or horrified, by how often I've seen the mathematical partial symbol instead of the schwa in linguistics texts ``:)``

Comment: @Sverre -- partial instead of schwa?!?  that *is* horrifying!  (i hope i never have the dubious pleasure!)

Comment: what do you mean by "sans-serif" partial? I don not see any serifs in this sign.

Comment: @MaxNoe I added an image to the post to clarify. Notice the slant, the varying stroke thickness, and the ball at the tip of the LaTeX version. I would ideally prefer something like the Helvetica version, which is upright and a single thickness throughout, as typical of a sans-serif font.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Partial solution.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand*\partial{\textsf{\reflectbox{6}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Pun ~ intended.

Comment: Wow, I love it for sheer cheek. I probably should choose a more generalizable solution as my accepted answer, but this is an amazingly clever one-liner quick fix.

Comment: Well, @thecommexokid, you didn't say what font you where using, so I guessed that (at least) you tried with `cmbright` and you didn't like the partial of that font, so I improvised a new one. In case you want the partial from *that* font (or whatever font you choose), the answer to your question is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/21930).

Comment: I am trying to understand the answers of the question you linked to. It seems as though I will need to know the character number of the `\partial` character within cmbright; how do I find that?

Comment: That's something I don't control pretty well, but doing a `\meaning\partial` inside a document, it will print its definition: in this case `\mathchar"140`. So, if I were to guess a number I would say `"140` :) I don't know how “people” in this site get/know those numbers, but in my case that's the only way I know (in case you are happy with the .log may be you prefer to use `\show\partial` rather than `\meaning\partial`).

Comment: Since I can't seem to make any of the more general solutions work for me, and since I personally don't foresee needing sans-serif versions of any other nonalphanumeric characters besides `\partial` in the future, I'm going to go ahead and accept your original thinking-outside-the-box answer and not spend any more time on the issue.

Answer (score 5):

How about using `cmbright` to get sans serif math and rotating the `\partial`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\upartial}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{15}{\ensuremath{\partial\mkern-2mu}}}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\quad\textnormal{vs.}\quad\frac{\upartial x}{\upartial t}\]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

One can get `cmbright` only in math mode with the following code. However, in doing so I discovered this solution is not very robust. As you can see in the image, the upright `\partial` gets typeset in `\displaystyle` despite being inside `\(...\)`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,cmbright}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\rmdefault}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\upartial}{\mathsurround=0pt \rotatebox[origin=c]{15}{$\partial\mkern-2mu$}}
\begin{document}
Normal vs.\ upright partial: \(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\) vs.\ \(\frac{\upartial x}{\upartial t}\)
\end{document}
```

Note: I've also changed the definition of `\upartial` after reading @egreg's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35877/24974), but the inline math problem persists.

Comment: `\usepackage{cmbright}` will typeset the entire document in sans-serif, no?

Comment: To clarify: I have no objection to using cmbright for my sans-serif font, and I like the look of the symbols in your screenshot the best of any of the suggested solutions. But my document is a mixture of serif and sans-serif type, so it is unacceptable to switch the *whole document* to cmbright. Is there a way to use cmbright *only* for my sans-serif needs?

Comment: @thecommexokid I've modified my answer to produce only sans serif math, but in doing so I found an issue with my proposed solution.

Comment: It doesn't use `\displaystyle` but `\textstyle`. You should take a look at `\mathpalette` and `\mathchoice`.

Comment: Re: "One can get cmbright only in math mode with the following code." Thank you for the attempted fix, but alas this is still not what I am trying to do. I do not wish to typeset all the math in my document in sans-serif, only some individual characters. All I want is `\somecommand` that does what I had naively expected `\mathsf{\partial}` to do. It's fine to use `cmbright` for *all my sans-serif* in the document; it's not fine to use it for *all my math*.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\def\uppartial{{\mathversion{sf}\ensuremath{\partialup}}}
\begin{document}
$\partial$ partial derivative symbol in \LaTeX

\sffamily
\uppartial{} partial derivative symbol in \LaTeX
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `\usepackage[partialup]{kpfonts}` if you do not need the default version. Then `\partial` is upright by default.

Comment: Hm. For me, the `\mathversion{sf}` in this definition seems to have no effect, and I am getting a symbol that, while it is upright, matches the style of the serif font family. It looks better in your picture.

Comment: I am using up-to-date TeXLive 2014 and version 3.31 of the kpfonts.