# Import one symbol from `fourier`

Tags: fonts, packages, incompatibility, fourier

I use `pxfonts` but  need the symbol `\danger` from `fourier`.

The answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27527/import-a-symbol-from-the-fourier-font-family) explains how to load from `fourier` just one symbol. Unfortunately, I am unable to adapt the solution to my case.

Comment: Add:`\usepackage{fourier} ` and can use `\danger` in your document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\danger` command is defined as a *text* symbol in `fourier-orns.sty`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\danger $abc\text{\danger}$

\end{document}
```

Prefer the more recent `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` to `pxfonts`; these two packages correct the shortcomings in the older package.

[image]

Comment: It works! Simpler that I expected. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @PrimoPetri Just be careful if using the symbols in math mode: use `\text` or `\mbox` around them.