# How do I create "double-struck" square brackets in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am writing some proofs using LaTeX, and following the standard procedure in the ConTeXt, I need to write something as follows:

[image]

However, I have no idea how to create the "double bracket", like the one includes `x := y + z`...

Could anyone give me some help on this?

Comment: The `fourier` package provides `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket`

Comment: Also `stmaryrd` package has `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket`. I think this site could be useful for you: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html.

Comment: Also notice, that `:=` should by typeset not as `:=`, but as `\coloneq`.

Comment: @Mico It is a duplicate, if one considers searching for `bracket` in the comprehensive list of symbols a solution.

Comment: @gernot - I think it would be helpful, in marking this posting as a duplicate, if it were pointed out *which one* of the currently 19 [!] answers to the posting "How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character" would actually be useful for the task at hand. The most-upvoted answer, which suggests using DeTeXify, doesn't do the job here.

Comment: @Mico The accepted and most-upvoted answer of the other thread offers three possibilities, with the first being to look the symbol up in the comprehensive list, so it is a duplicate. But I agree that detexify alone would not be a satisfactory answer as it misses many symbols.

Comment: For completeness in the links, I'll note that https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81785/86 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252648/86 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139891/86 all deal with the same issue (though most are closed as duplicates of the more general "How to look up a symbol" question)

Comment: An interesting related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100966/defining-scalable-white-curly-brackets-and-and

Comment: If you use `unicode-math`, you can just use the Unicode characters ⟦ (U+27E6) and ⟧ (U+27E7). They work nicely with `\big` and `\left`/`\right` and the like. (Sadly I cannot post this as an answer.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` from `fourier` package (for example) for those doubled bracket symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}    
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
 $ f_{Z} \llbracket x \coloneqq y + z\rrbracket (\sigma) = [ x \mapsto Z ] (\sigma)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If using the whole `fourier` package is too much, importing symbols might be an option: [Import one symbol from `fourier`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356841/import-one-symbol-from-fourier?s=1|3.0749)

Here's the version with import of the symbols (code copied from `fourier.sty`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}%
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{futm}{m}{it}%
\DeclareFontEncoding{FMS}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FMS}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontEncoding{FMX}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{FMS}{futm}{m}{n}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}%

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\llbracket}{\mathopen}{symbols}{153}{largesymbols}{133}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rrbracket}{\mathclose}{symbols}{154}{largesymbols}{134}


\begin{document}
$ f_{Z} \llbracket x \coloneqq y + z\rrbracket (\sigma) = [ x \mapsto Z ] (\sigma)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note the difference between the regular symbols `f`, `x` etc. from the screen shots.

Comment: You anticipated me for a few minutes and of course I voted positively for your answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano: As I have done vice versa

Comment: I imagined and for me it is also a sign of respect and esteem for your great talent.

Answer (score 20):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f_Z\llbracket  x: y z t   \rrbracket      
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The downvote here is not justified!

Comment: I always hope I have done my best. There are much better than me users and faster me.A they always go my compliments.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The downvote (not mine) it's probably because this answer is equal to my comment I posted one minute before...

Comment: With so much Christian sincerity, it seems to me that someone is doing it for purpose. If you look at each answer I provide there is always a negative vote even if it is good or discreet.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: That's a coincidence then, I think. Sometimes I post an answer and see that somebody has posted a comment in between -- it's hard to recognize this.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I think so, that's why _I_ did not downvote...

Comment: When I write a document in LaTeX with Papeeria I do not see any comment at all and focus exclusively on the question. With so much sincerity I answer only simple questions. That's why I have very little reputation. I have a slow connection and any update to the question or comments to me is delayed.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I thank you so much, but this is not the point. At this time, at least for an hour I'm in the car with my pc, with a very slow connection. Honestly, I have been reproached by all over the world for a few months. It's not that they are not right, but there seems to be little respect for me.

Comment: @Sebastiano, you have my respect, sir :)

Comment: @computereasy Thanks a lot very very much for you and for my friends.

Comment: This is the best answer in the lot: no complicated code for borrowing symbols from bigger families. I find the downvote completely unjustified.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the `fourier` and `stmaryd` packages, the `mathabx` package also provides "double-struck" square brackets; the macro names are `\ldbrack` and `\rdbrack`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx} % for `\ldbrack` and `\rdbrack` macros
\begin{document}
$ f_{Z} \ldbrack x := y + z\rdbrack (\sigma) = [x\mapsto Z]\sigma$     
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico, I have votated also your answer. But why does anyone always give me negative votes? :(

Comment: @Sebastiano - Wow, I have no idea why anyone would have downvoted your answer! That's just awful behavior. Do rest assured that I *upvoted* your answer.

Comment: I don't recommend loading `mathabx`: it changes *all* symbols and some of them become quite peculiar.

Answer (score 10):

If you do not want `mathabx` to replace the default symbol fonts, you can define commands only for the symbols, which are extensible, with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{ <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8>
matha7 <8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9 <10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
%
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8>
mathx7 <8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9 <10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\ldbrack} {4}{matha}{"76}{mathx}{"30}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rdbrack} {5}{matha}{"77}{mathx}{"38}

\begin{document}

    \[ f_{Z} \bigl\ldbrack x \coloneqq y + z\bigr\rdbrack(\sigma) = [x\mapsto Z]\sigma \]

\end{document}
```

Also,  do  not use `:=`: the colon is not centred on the math axis. With the standard fonts, `mathtools` defines a `\coloneqq` command, wich produces a correct version.

[image]