# Create a new double bracket symbol, or properly scale the existing one

Tags: symbols, unicode-math, mathtools

In my document there already exists a math font configuration, but it doesn't contain the symbol for double brackets. Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367529/194994), I imported the one from the `fourier` font.

However, as can be seen from the picture, the symbol looks too small compare to the normal bracket:

[image]

Actually I think even `[\mkern-4mu[` looks better, but unfortunately this does not work with `\left` and `\right`.

Thus, my question is that, would it be possible to scale these imported symbols? Or, even better, is there some way to define this symbol to look like `[\mkern-4mu[` (thus consistent with the current math font) but can be automatically scaled with `\left` and `\right` (without having to write `\left[\mkern-4mu\left[`)?

Below is a MWE. *To me the `\mkern-4mu` one is the most beautiful one, and I would be really apprieciable to know a way to define `\llbracket` as this.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon, mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style = ISO, partial = upright, nabla = upright}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}%
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{futm}{m}{it}%
\DeclareFontEncoding{FMS}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FMS}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontEncoding{FMX}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{FMS}{futm}{m}{n}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}%

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\llbracket}{\mathopen}{symbols}{153}{largesymbols}{133}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rrbracket}{\mathclose}{symbols}{154}{largesymbols}{134}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \( K  \llbracket X \rrbracket  [X]  [\mkern-4mu[ X ]\mkern-4mu]  \)
\end{center}

\[
    \left\llbracket \frac{X}{Y} \right\rrbracket  \left[ \frac{X}{Y} \right]  \left[\mkern-4mu\left[ \frac{X}{Y} \right]\mkern-4mu\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use different names than `symbols` and `largesymbols`; then you can scale the symbols font scaled.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon, mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style = ISO, partial = upright, nabla = upright}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{futm}{m}{it}
\DeclareFontEncoding{FMS}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FMS}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontEncoding{FMX}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}

\DeclareFontFamily{FMS}{futm}{\skewchar \font =48}
\DeclareFontShape{FMS}{futm}{m}{n}{<-> s * [1.2] futsy}{}

%\DeclareFontFamily{FMX}{futm}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}{<-> s * [0.92] fourier-mex}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{fouriersymbols}{FMS}{futm}{m}{n}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{fourierlargesymbols}{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}%

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\llbracket}{\mathopen}{fouriersymbols}{153}{fourierlargesymbols}{133}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rrbracket}{\mathclose}{fouriersymbols}{154}{fourierlargesymbols}{134}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\( K  \llbracket X \rrbracket  [X] \)
\end{center}

\[
\left\llbracket \frac{X}{Y} \right\rrbracket  \left[ \frac{X}{Y} \right]  
\]

\end{document}
```

I reported (commented out) the setting for the large symbols font.

[image]

Experiment with various scaling factors, but you'll not get good alignment anyway.

A different strategy might be to do

```
\usepackage[only,llbracket,rrbracket]{stmaryrd}
```

instead of importing from `fourier`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! I was aware of the `stmaryrd` approach, but this package seems to be very old and the appearance is not very consistent with the main font. By the way, do you think defining `\llbracket` with normal bracket and `\mkern-4mu` would be possible? I'm not sure if there is a way to read in and pass the `\left` to every bracket.

Comment: @Jinwen I believe that the simplest strategy would be to convince the maintainer of Kpfonts to add the double brackets.

Comment: Thank you, now that you mentioned it, I took a look at the CTAN page of `kpfonts-otf` and surprisingly found in the attached glyph demonstration file that `unicode-math` already has `\lBrack` and `\rBrack` for this, which are even more perfect than my `\mkern-4mu` version.